# Url for cities/regions/countries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

What do you recommend for displaying URLs and handling views in Rails for cities, regions, countries?

i.e:

/us/ca/San-Fransisco

/countries/us/regions/ca/cities/San-Fransisco

Should be able to:
List all countries, list all regions within country and list all cities within a region and country.

Where would you put code for displaying all regions in a country?:

/us/regions/

/us

Should the code be in the region (action show) or country (action index) controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Arne. I don't see any problem with the first variant.

As for the second question, you better get the list of regions in the RegionsController.

Say you want to

```
GET /us/regions
```

then you should route it to

```
class RegionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /:country_code/regions
  # GET /regions
  def index
    @countries = 
      if params[:country_code]
        Country.find_by_code(params[:country_code]).regions
      else
        Region.all # get all regions if country_code is not set
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: but that is not the url that Arne says: /us/ which would list regions. In your case, what would /us/ output?

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice. I was a bit sleepy, sorry. Nonetheless, you need one URL that will identify a country and one URL to identify a collection of its states. And here, you are free to decide. You can make /us to be the URL of the country or the URL of the regions(states).

Comment: If you'll go for the first option, you'll need one extra URL for collection of regions (that's what I did).In the second case, you'd need one extra URL for the country (which could be eg. /countries/us). The URL for region stays the same - eg. /us/ca. So, it's up to you which one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the simple /us/ca/San-Fransisco. A shorter path will result in a listing:

- / lists countries
- /us lists us states
- /us/ca lists californian cities

Simple, short, clean - and will be honored by google ;-)